# Combining + andPredicateWithSubpredicates: and + orPredicateWithSubpredicates: in one predicate

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, predicate

I want to set a compound predicate with next subpredicates:

- id  (AND type)
- firstname (OR type)
- lastname (OR type)
- middlename (OR type)

I am reading [NSCompoundPredicate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but don't understand clear enough - is it possible at all to use both `+ andPredicateWithSubpredicates:` and `+ orPredicateWithSubpredicates:` to combine them as one predicate in one fetch request?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved this way:

objc:

```
NSPredicate *orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[firstPredicate, secondPredicate]];
NSPredicate *andPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[thirdPredicate, fourthPredicate]];
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[orPredicate, andPredicate]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:finalPredicate];
```

Swift:

```
let orPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [firstPredicate, secondPredicate])
let andPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [thirdPredicate, fourthPredicate])
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [orPredicate, andPredicate])
```

Comment: You can combine the second and third step to `NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[orPredicate, thirdPredicate, fourthPredicate]]`.